# systemctl service starts executable but shuts down right after it

Tags: 16.04, java, systemd

The launch-service.sh file should be executed by the phantombot.service file.
I looked in systemctl service phantombot if the service actually started. The service starts and gets closed after about 11 seconds. (see below)

`launch-service.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# PhantomBot Launcher - Linux and macOS
#
# Please run the following to launch the bot, the chmod is required only once.
# % chmod +x launch-service.sh
# % ./launch-service.sh
#

unset DISPLAY

if [[ $(uname) -eq "Darwin" ]]; then
    SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
    while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
        DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
        SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
        [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
    done
    DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
    cd "$DIR"
else
    cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
fi

if type -p java 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    _java=java
elif [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]];  then
    _java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
    echo "You don't have Java installed! Download it from https://www.java.com/en/download/"
fi

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar
```

`/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=PhantomBot
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
User=botuser
Group=botuser
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
KillSignal=SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This shows systemctl status right after i started the service:

```
$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:08:14 CEST; 21min ago
  Process: 13145 ExecStart=/home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 13145 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
botuser@Ubuntu-1704-zesty-64-minimal:~/phantombot$ sudo /bin/systemctl start phantombot

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:18 CEST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 13295 (launch-service.)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/phantombot.service
           ├─13295 /bin/bash /home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
           └─13300 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:18 CEST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 13295 (launch-service.)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/phantombot.service
           ├─13295 /bin/bash /home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
           └─13300 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:18 CEST; 5s ago
 Main PID: 13295 (launch-service.)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/phantombot.service
           ├─13295 /bin/bash /home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
           └─13300 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:18 CEST; 9s ago
 Main PID: 13295 (launch-service.)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/phantombot.service
           ├─13295 /bin/bash /home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
           └─13300 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:18 CEST; 11s ago
 Main PID: 13295 (launch-service.)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/phantombot.service
           ├─13295 /bin/bash /home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh
           └─13300 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar PhantomBot.jar

$ systemctl status phantombot
● phantombot.service - PhantomBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/phantombot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:30:31 CEST; 703ms ago
  Process: 13295 ExecStart=/home/botuser/phantombot/launch-service.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 13295 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

You see the service actually started for like 11 seconds until it shutdown.
If i execute the .`/launch-service.sh` file directly via commandline it doesn't shutdown.

I followed [this guide](https://community.phantombot.tv/t/ubuntu-16-04-lts-setup-guide/61) step by step.

Thanks for any help in andvanced. :)

Any sugestions whats going wrong here?

Is this a permission problem? Can I execute it in some kind of verbose mode to see the errors that shut down the deamon?

Comment: Did your restart your system so the new user will be recognized?

Comment: do you mean if i restarted systemctl deamon or the whole server? i just restarted systemctl

Comment: i restarted the server now also. didnt make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for updating the Question so it meets the conventions

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake. 
It was a permission error.
Some logfiles the javascript files wanted to access were ownd by root. 
That made the init.js file throw a Permission denied error that i found in journalctl via the command `sudo journalctl -u phantombot -b`.

I really wonder how program got started the first time without any errors.

But anyways thanks for the help.